# TypeError in __init__(), unexpected argument python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, init

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Button:   
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame( master )
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text = "Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side = LEFT)

    def printMessage(self):
        print(" WORKING!! " )       



root = Tk()
b = Button(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Which does not seem to be wrong in anyway... But when I run it, terminal says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "class.py", line 23, in <module>
b = Button(root)
File "class.py", line 10, in __init__
self.printButton = Button(frame, text = "Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'command'
```

I wrote all these codes according to a tkinter tutorial. And in the tutorial, the code works well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are just creating another instance of your own `Button` class.  Try renaming it to `CustomButton`.

Comment: Lots of Tkinter example code uses `from tkinter import *` but you have now discovered why this is a **bad** idea.

Comment: @PM2Ring , Whenever I learn some basics like this one you mentioned, my life makes even more sense :P . Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: My pleasure! FWIW, when you do `from tkinter import *` you import over 170 names (in Python 2, I'm not sure of the exact figure in Python 3). Not only is that annoying because of the potential clash with names you define yourself, but there's an even bigger problem. Imagine what happens if you then do `import *` with another big module. Names in the new module can clobber the names from the Tkinter module, which will leading to weird bugs. Hopefully, the code will just fail to run, giving a helpful error message. But it's possible that it _will_ run, but just not do what you expect it to.

Comment: @PM2RING  That sounds like, executing a secret combination to create an evil artificial intelligence :P . I will never use " import * " again... or, dont you think it worths trying?? oh okay nevermind, to much sci-fic :)  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tkinter already has a `Button`class and when you create your class you now have overwritten the tkinter class named `Button`. So, when you try to create a tkinter button like this:

```
self.printButton = Button(frame, text = "Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
```

You are now referencing **your** button because you overwrote the tkinter button previously. And since your button only takes one argument and you give it three, It will throw you an error. The way to fix this would be to change your import line to this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

And then reference any tkinter functions with `tk.*`. For example:

```
root = Tk()
```

would become:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

Then your button would be referenced by `Button` while the tkinter button would be referenced by `tk.Button`. This way you could easily distingush between the two. However you could also just call your button something like `myButton` which would also fix the problem.

Comment: "you now have two classes named `Button`". I get what you mean, but that's not strictly true since you can't have two things with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. How would you word it instead?

Comment: Maybe something like: "Two different things in the same scope can't have the same name, so when you create your `Button` class it replaces the previous `Button` class defined by Tkinter". And maybe give an example illustrating the same thing with simple variables, eg `a='one'; a=1`

Comment: Thanks so very much everybody! That s a very clear answer.